# Timeout expired. Only in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

With `SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout` and `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` set to infinite (0), my desktop application will wait indefinite. However, my ASP.NET application won't. No connections are being leaked, and there is plenty of system memory.

I suspect ASP.NET is secretly setting timeouts, but even with `HttpRuntimeSection.ExecutionTimeout` set to 30 minutes. I'm still encountering a timeout exception.

Are there other timeout variables in ASP.NET that I'm not aware of? Or is anyone aware what could be causing this?

**Update:** Stack Trace

```
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.QuietOpen(IDbConnection connection, ConnectionState& originalState)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
at FrostWebsite._default.GetQuickStats()
at FrostWebsite._default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have timeout exception form ASP.NET, not from SQL. There is a way to exceed asp.net timeout. Example here: http://weblogs.asp.net/aghausman/archive/2009/02/20/prevent-request-timeout-in-asp-net.aspx